# How do you summon Daemons in 40k?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I bought the Chaos Daemon Tzeentch start collecting box and realized that other armies can summon daemons so I don't have to just play a Daemon army. But I don't know how that would work.

Lets say you are a Chaos Space Marine Army, under what circumstances can you summon a Daemon unit? What phase of combat would it happen and is there any downside?

For example, how could I summon Horrors of Tzeentch?

Comment: Do you have a copy of the [Warhammer 40,000 Core Rules](https://warhammer40000.com/rules/)?

Comment: The rules for summoning are in [Codex: Chaos Daemons](https://www.games-workshop.com/en-GB/Codex-Chaos-Daemons-hb-english-2018)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Choas Character can can summon Daemons that have the Daemon Ritual keyword. They can be summoned during the movement phase in place of taking a move action.

The downside is you cannot take a move action on that turn with the summoning character. But also and more importantly the summoning (in a match game) requires you to have available resources left (points).

To complete the summoning, roll 3D6 and you can place Daemon models whose power level are below the outcome of the dice roll.

Example of play; You have 50 points remaining for your army list. On your turn your Daemon Prince Character chooses to summon daemons.

You roll 3D6 and achieved a result of 9, you could summon a few Pink Horrors. The Daemon Prince cannot move on that turn because they summoned daemons in the movement phase rather than moving. And you must expend the points associated with the Pink Horrors or any other daemon models you table.

Comment: Is this specifically for Matched Play, and if so, how do the rules vary when playing a game with armies built using Power Levels?

Comment: @nick012000 i would add that info but i don’t know how power levels works.